# Wp7 - Increasing touch response time

Tags: silverlight, performance, windows-phone-7, event-handling, touch

i read that if you pan the surface of a touchscreen with Windows Phone 7 os, the TouchFrameEventHandler will be triggered every 15-25 milliseconds. Is there a way to faster trigger the event?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No.
There's no way to override the speed at which events are raised. There are multiple factors which control the speed at which these events are raised.

Do you have a specific issue you're trying to resolve by doing this?

Comment: I'm creating something like a piano, i'd like to play all the notes when i sweep my finger on the keys but the response is too slow and some notes would not play at all. I think that the problem is caused by the high response time of the touch event.

Comment: @Daniele In addition to detecting the touch event on each "key" you could look at adding a gesture to detect the sweep and play all the relevant keys/sounds. You shoudl also look to make sure that there's nothing else happening within your app which could be affecting overall performance.

Comment: I solved using CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the images. Thank you very much for your answers!